# Optimizing code for UVAJ 573 The Snail

Tags: c++, programming-challenge

I'm getting the right results for the code for the sample outputs, but the OJ is giving a TLE (3 seconds max).

The questions is [here](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/5/573.pdf).

```
int main()
{
    double h,u,d,f;
    while(scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf",&h,&u,&d,&f)!=EOF)
    {
        //cin>>h;
       // if(h==0)
          //  break;
        //cin>>u>>d>>f;
        double fu=.01*f*u;
        double used_fu=0;
        int day=1;
        double crossed=0;
        int success=0;
        while(1)
        {
            crossed+=(u-used_fu);
            if(crossed>h)
            {
                success++;break;
            }
            crossed-=d;
            if(crossed<0)
                break;
            used_fu+=fu;
            day++;
        }
        if(success==0)
            cout<<"failure";
        else
            cout<<"success";
        cout<<" on day "<<day<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UVAJ573 may mean something to you, but it means nothing to me.  Consider updating your title and question so that it describes what it is your code is supposed to be doing, not just what you're hoping for from the review/linking to external sites.

Answer (score 1):

So first things first, your code looks terrible.

1. Use real names for your variables that are understandable without any further reading, e.g. instead of `fu` you could use `fatique`.
2. Your variable success is a boolean so make it one.
3. You should introduce a factor for the fatique rather than subtracting it. That would make the code simpler. Also your failure is most likely because the snail takes so much time to slide back down. So rather than checking for `snailHeight > 0` check for `heightSlid > fatique * heightClimbed`

   ```
   size_t numDays = 0;
   double snailHeight = 0.0;
   double fatique = 1.0;
   bool fail = false;
   while (true) {
       numDays++;
       snailHeight += fatique * heightClimbed;
       fatique *= 0.9;
       if (heightSlid > fatique * heightClimbed) {
           fail = true;
           break;
       } else if (snailHeight > heightWell) {
           break;
       }

       snailHeight -= heightSlid;
   }

   if (fail) {
       std::cout << "failure\n";
   } else {
       std::cout << "success on day " << numDays << "\n";
   }
   ```